# How to make QtQuick transparent Toolbar

Tags: qml, toolbar, qt-quick, qtquick2

How to make the built-in `Quick ToolBar` transparent so that only buttons are visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3` and Qt 5.2 you can use `ToolBarStyle`, i.e. you can write something like this (obviously with whatever padding you prefer):

```
toolBar:ToolBar {

    style: ToolBarStyle {
        padding {
            left: 0
            right: 0
            top: 0
            bottom: 0
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "transparent"
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ToolButton {
            text: "Button 1"
        }
        ToolButton {
            text: "Button 2"
            style: ButtonStyle {
                background: Rectangle {

                    border.width: control.activeFocus ? 4 : 1
                    border.color: "#888"
                    radius: 4
                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#eee" : "#fff" }
                        GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#fff" : "#aaa" }
                    }
                }

                label: Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    minimumPixelSize : 8
                    fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit
                    font.pixelSize: 15
                    text: "open"
                    color: "red"
                    font.bold: true
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
        }
        ToolButton {
            text: "Button 3"
        }
        Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }
        CheckBox {
            text: "Enabled"
            checked: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The toolbar is invisible for me, only the checkbox square is visible.

Comment: The icons are loaded asynchrously from the Internet and it can take some seconds (or cannot work if your Internet connection is not available). I've edited the code and set some text in place of the icons. If you use local resources it works perfectly fine.

Comment: The color of the ToolButton text is black that is why it was invisible. Do you know how to change the color?

Comment: You can use [`ButtonStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html). Mind that, when you change a style, the default system styling is **totally** lost. Which means you cannot adjust just one property but change the styling as a whole. I've edited to add an example.

Comment: And the button background is visible now. Do you know how to keep the button look same as the look of the other buttons which use the default style but with different font color?

Comment: What I wrote? If you style a part you have to style everything of the control. Hence, the solution is to (try to) copy the default style of the desktop system. Try to dig inside QML style sources for the "desktop" directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72812/discussion-between-programmist-and-bacarozzo).

Answer (score 0):

You are not obliged to use `ToolBar`, it can be any visual item, for example here I use semi-transparent blue rectangle as toolbar:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true
    toolBar: Rectangle {
        color: Qt.rgba(0,0,255,0.5)
        width: parent.width
        height: 30
        Row {
            ToolButton {
                text: "Button1"
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: "Button2"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Or, in your case you just can use `Row`:

```
toolBar: Row {   
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it works, but I am interested in using the ToolBar.